Import Sandbox with Test Data for non developers
The use case here is that we want to import sandbox with test data having parent child relationship in a single go. One way to do it would be to use sf commands -
sf data import tree --plan Account-Contact-plan.json

Or if your project is configured using Cumulus CI, you can use Snowfakery to create dataset recipes and execute the cci task commands to load test data into sandbox/scratch org.
However, both of the above methods involve a developer running the commands in the CLI.
Is there any way I can have a button or a URL in my GitHub repo which can redirect the admin to org login page and post login, automatically run the necessary sf or cci commands

Is it too difficult to supply the user with a script to run the command?

Or is it the having the tools installed that is the problem?

@PhilW Its mainly the roadblocks of having the necessary tools installed and also the training associated with it

Tool install is a fair reason. Training no so much. "Double-click the script icon on the desktop" doesn't need a whole lot of training... regardless, is there also a question about the test data: should it always be the same? Or should users define their own?

Yeah, the test data which needs to be generated can be the same

I would consider simply including a static resource will the required data description, and having the package/org include a specific screen flow, that can appear as a quick action on some screen, that invokes some apex that uses the content of the static resource to generate the required test data.

Yes. You should be able to use a GitHub Action, such that a user with sufficient permissions can automatically log in and have the data populated. Integrations with Jenkins or Cumulus CI shouldn't involve the admin running scripts directly. You could create a Visualforce page/Lightning Component that they can navigate to in order to create the data. If they're using the Salesforce UI to create sandboxes, the SandboxPostCopy interface allows them to select a class to use. You could code something and have an integration hosted on Heroku or AWS EB for just a couple of dollars a month. Third-party programs like AutoRABIT and GearSet should be able to automate the process of creating all kinds of complicated record relationships at the click of a button.
Note: product/service names mentioned are not endorsements. Do your own research for product/service features before choosing a product/service.

+1 for github actions, using them on several of my projects, very convinient.

Unless you use a different git provider like Bitbucket. In which case it is Bitbucket pipelines that use the Salesforce CLI Docker image, with triggering of the pipeline through the Bitbucket UI.

(Yes, the OP uses github)

Just so that I am on the same page here, digging deeper into the GitHub action solution, we need to have a YML file setup which can authorize the org using JWT/SFDX Auth file and run the necessary sf data import commands. This file will run as part of CI/CD pipeline automatically or manually.
Are you referring to this or am I completely off track here

@AdityaM Honestly, I haven't used GitHub Actions, but it sounds like you're on the right path.
